# jQuery .removeClass issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have a Glossary I use on my website, that utilizes a some show/hide functionality and a .removeClass attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#glossary-container li").click(function() { 
        $(".glossary-content > div").hide();
        var id = $(this).attr("id").replace('-link', ''); 
        $('#' + id).show(); 

        $(".glossaryUL li").each(function() { 
            $(this).click(function() {
                $(".glossaryUL li").removeClass("selected");                       
                $(this).addClass("selected"); 
                elementClick = $(this).attr("id"); 
            });
        });
    }); 

    $('.coolbox').hide(); 

    $('.clicker').click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $($(this).attr('href')).toggle(300); 
    });
});
```

On page load, the list item letter "A" the UL lass ".glossaryUL" is set via inline styles as "selected".

```
<li id="a-link" class="selected">A</li>
```

When you click on another letter, the terms inside of class ".glossary-content" display, but the .removeClass attribute does not remove the class from the letter "A".

However, if you then click on another letter (your 2nd click after page load), the .removeClass attribute functions and removes the class and applies it to the proper letter...

I can not figure out why it is doing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle demonstrating this situation?

Comment: Your jQuery code seems a little erratic. Could you post the HTML you have, as this should be possible in about 5 lines of code.

Comment: Hi, no time to answer to you, but give a check-search about ( ...on(event){ event.prevent ...)  since **event** is a reserved word. Maybe i am all wrong and don't want to induce in bad direction, just point some bad bugs souvenirs of mine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wrap your click event assignments into an `each`, jQuery will already assign the `click` event for **every** element that matches that selector (because you used a class as selector). I suspect you have duplicate click events conflicting. Try this instead:

```
$(".glossaryUL li").click(function() { 
        $(".glossaryUL li").removeClass("selected");                       
        $(this).addClass("selected"); 
        elementClick = $(this).attr("id"); 
    });
});
```